# How can one rewrite $x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$ for $k = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

While trying to prove one expression via mathematical induction, I've came to the dead end – I can't deduce, which form will sequences $x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$ and $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k)$ take for k = 0. How can I find it?

Comment: They're empty products, so they're equal to one.

Comment: @j___d could you, please, write it in expanded way? I can't get it.

Comment: We're multiplying by smaller and smaller numbers, but since $x<x-k+1$ and $x-1<x-k$ for $k=0$, *nothing* is being multiplied here. Hence, it's equal to multiplicative identity, one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $x(x-1) \cdots (x-n+1)$ is ambiguous when $n=0$.  A text defining this product should give a separate definition for this case.  For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) writes

> The value of each is taken to be 1 (an empty product) when n=0.

Since the formula is ambiguous, in some sense it's a matter of choice how to define it when $n=0$.  But there are a number of good reasons why it's more convenient to set it to $1$.  This is similar to the situation with something like $x^n$.  If you write your own textbook, I suppose you could define $x^n = 7$ when $n = 0$, but your formulas would quickly become very ugly with a lot of special cases when $n=0$.

Here are some good reasons why $x(x-1) \cdots (x-n+1)$ should be $1$ when $n =0$:

- It's an example of an [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) which is generally taken to be $1$ for many reasons (see the link.)
- We would like to write $x(x-1) \cdots (x-n+1) = n!{ x \choose n}$, and we have $n! = {x \choose n} = 1$ when $n=0$, again because they are empty products.
- There's a combinatorial interpretation for $x(x-1) \cdots (x-n+1)$: it's the number of ways to choose $n$ labeled balls from a bucket containing $x$ labeled balls, without replacement, in some order.  If $n=0$ there's exactly one way to choose them: don't choose any.

Comment: This is a good answer to the general question of how to define empty products. Since the question didn't say exactly how the formula was used, I can't be _sure_ it will work well in the context where OP wants to use it, but it seems to me very likely that it will.

Comment: So, mine sequence can be rewritten as $\Pi_{u = 1}^{u = k}(x-u)$, and when $k = 0$ so is $u$ and then the product is empty? Do I get it right?

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity Exactly, yes.

Comment: Actually, on second thought I realized I hadn't noticed your second form $(x-1) \cdots (x-k)$.  This is ambiguous when $k=0$ but it's not as standard.    You could write it as $\frac{(k+1)!}{x} {x \choose k+1}$; there it's clear that it should be $1$ when $k=0$.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity When you don't add any numbers, the result should be $0$ because adding in something to the nothing must be equal to itself.  When you don't multiply any numbers, the result should be $1$ because multiplying in something to the $1$ must be equal, again, to itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to prove something by mathematical induction, an alternative is to let $k=1$ be the base case rather than $k=0$.  Then (assuming you can prove the induction step) you can conclude that the claim is true for all $k \ge 1$.

Comment: What claim is true?  All the OP wants to know is the case $k=0$, and induction like you've explained does not get you there.

Comment: @SimpleArt The full text of the OP's question said that the reason for asking about the case $k=0$ is because he or she is trying to prove something (we do not know what) via induction.  My point is that the case $k=0$ may not even be necessary for that purpose, and rather than trying to choose a convention for the $k=0$ case it might be more sensible to start with $k=1$, which is unambiguous.